# Does anyone have a CheXpert dataset?

Tags: download, dataset, x-ray

We tried to download the CheXpert dataset from site https://stanfordaimi.azurewebsites.net/datasets/8cbd9ed4-2eb9-4565-affc-111cf4f7ebe2,
but the following error occurred.

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

`BlobNotFound`
The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:275caf17-c01e-0028-6e26-5389dd000000 Time:2024-01-30T02:45:13.2114097Z

I think there is a problem with the site itself.

If you have a solution or the corresponding dataset, please share.

Additionally, I tried through Azure, but the download did not work.

I tried downloading and hoping to get the dataset.